# ServiceStack - prevent unauthorized access to static files

Tags: authentication, static, authorization, servicestack

I understand there is more than one way of handling service authentication/authorization, but I cannot make it work for static files.

Is there a way of configuring the behavior to be the same as with services; if not authenticated a request to index.html should redirect to login page the same as a request to secured dto/service.

I am currently looking into RawHttpHandlers but since it is too early in the pipeline how do I get the authentication setup in the apphost config?

thanks in advance
Gjergji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use `IAppHost.RawHttpHandlers` because that's the only custom handler in [ServiceStack's Request Pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) that gets executed before the built-in static file handling is accessed.

But you should still be able to access the Users Session with the available extension methods, e.g:

```
this.RawHttpHandlers.Add(httpReq =>
{
    var isStaticFileRequest = httpReq.PathInfo.StartsWith("/static");
    if (isStaticFileRequest)
    {
        var session = httpReq.GetSession();
        if (!session.HasRole("TheRole"))
            return new ForbiddenHttpHandler();
    }
    return null;
});
```

This handler simply checks if it's a request for a static file, in this case the path info starts with `/static`, and if is checks the user session if they have the required role, if not it returns a Forbidden request, otherwise it returns `null` to tell ServiceStack to continue executing the request.

Note: if it's needed you can access any registered dependency from outside of ServiceStack with **HostContext.Resolve**, e.g:

```
var authRepo = HostContext.Resolve<IAuthRepository>();
```